# How to fix square root symbol from deforming?

Tags: symbols

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$$\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}$$

\end{document}
```

[image: the top left part of the root is not aligned]

The top left part of the root is not aligned with the rest. How do I fix it?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I have the old root setup in preamble, but the break occurs with or without the closed root.

Comment: It's just a viewer problem.

Comment: Ok, so if I print it, it'll be fine?

Comment: It should. Let me check for similar questions